# Hover Not Working on Button Inside Slider

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm going bonkers over here. This is pretty basic. I have 5 slider images and each one has a black button linking to a gallery. I want to change the background colour on hover on the button but it's only working on the children slider.

I'm fairly certain it's a positioning issue, but I've tried adding z-index values to the `.banner-text` div, but it's not making a difference.

[Here is the website.](http://dev.sandytherouxphotography.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that your `.slides ul li` have absolute positioning and they all have exact the same `z-index`. The slider library seems to only animate opacity of the images inside `<li>` elements. Therefore all your `<li>` elements present and on top of each other. It's causing the hover issue, because hover/click/etc. will not go through absolute element to the bottom one.

Children slider works because it's the topmost slide. You can test it by simply dragging another slide to be the last one and the button on it will work.

As a solution I suggest you to assign `z-index: -1` to all inactive slides. I don't know if it's possible in your case. Maybe you need to look for a different slider library.

UPD: Slick is a good replacement for your current lib by the way. http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ . I used it couple time and it's very clean and customizable.

Comment: That makes sense. I don't think I can make it work with the way this slider is setup. Client just emailed anyways and is ditching the buttons lol so it all works out. Thanks